# Dynamically changed polling interval

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, polling

I need my frontend application to poll my backend application and refresh the displayed data. I solved it in a certain way, but I have a feeling that it could be optimized. Here's my solution:

```
        this.pollDataSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.pollingInterval);

        this.pollDataSource$
            .pipe(
                switchMap(duration =>
                    of(duration)
                        .pipe(
                            filter(duration => duration !== 0),
                            delay(duration),
                            concatMap(() => this.kubernetesObjectList$)
                        )
                )
            )
            .subscribe({
                next: (kubernetesObjectList) => {
                    this.dataSource.data = kubernetesObjectList;
                    if (this.pollingInterval > 0) {
                        this.pollDataSource$.next(this.pollingInterval);
                    }
                }
            });

        this.pollDataSource$.next(-1);
```

So, I have a drop-down selector which affects `this.pollingInterval`. Also, I have `this.pollDataSource$` which is a `BehaviorSubject<number>`. It emits a `number` which is being used as the duration before the next poll.

When `this.pollDataSource$` emits `-1` (it happens when the user clicks the *Refresh* button), the data source must be polled immediately, disregarding what polling interval is set.

When `this.pollDataSource$` emits some positive number (it happens when a user selects a certain polling interval from the drop-down selector), this number must be used as the duration before the next refresh.

When `this.pollDataSource$` emits `0` (it happens when a user selects the *Stop Polling* option in the same drop-down selector), we must stop polling until the user selects a new polling interval.

And things work just perfectly. The page is loaded, `this.pollingInterval` has `10000` by default, so the user gets the data immediately, but in 10 seconds it's being updated. When the user hits *Refresh*, the data is being updated and the next automatic refresh happens after 10 seconds since that. When the user switches to *Stop Polling*, the data stay still. When the user switches to another interval, the data is being updated again. Everything's great! But I have a feeling that my solution is not optimal. I just don't like that construction: `...pipe...switchMap...of...pipe...` Is there a way to simplify that?

Thanks in advance for all the clues.

Comment: Look at `expand` operator

Comment: Thank you, @Picci. I have to admit that I'm feeling a bit more dumb than always, because I can't see the solution with `expand`. Would you be so kind as to help me to understand something that might be obvious for an experienced user of RxJS, but seems to be too complicated for a noob like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was mentioning `expand` is that this operator can be used instead of the construct

```
someSubject.pipe(
  // do stuff
).subscribe(
  next: data => {
    // do some more stuff
    someSubject.next(something)
  }
```

This is the construct you are actually using, therefore the suggestion about `expand`.

Then, getting back to your question without introducing `expand`, what you may consider is something like

```
this.pollDataSource$
        .pipe(
            switchMap(duration =>
                return duration === 0 ?
                  NEVER :
                  this.kubernetesObjectList$.pipe(delay(duration));
            )
        )
        .subscribe({
            next: (kubernetesObjectList) => {
                this.dataSource.data = kubernetesObjectList;
                if (this.pollingInterval > 0) {
                    this.pollDataSource$.next(this.pollingInterval);
                }
            }
        });

    this.pollDataSource$.next(-1);
```

With `expand` it could look like

```
this.pollDataSource$
            .pipe(
                expand(duration =>
                    return duration === 0 ?
                      NEVER :
                      this.kubernetesObjectList$.pipe(
                         delay(duration),
                         map(() =>  duration)
                      );
                )
            )
            .subscribe({
                next: (kubernetesObjectList) => {
                    this.dataSource.data = kubernetesObjectList;
                }
            });

        this.pollDataSource$.next(-1);
```

Whether these versions of the code are cleaner that your original one, which I found clear and readable, is probably a matter of personal taste.

All the "could" and "would" I have used are due to the fact that I do not have a playground where to test this code, so it is very much possible that you will find something not working here.

Comment: Note that `delay` doesn't delay when the actual "polling" takes place, it just slows down the value after you've already received it. If that makes sense.

Comment: @Ben Lesh your comment makes perfect sense, and it is a mistake I often jump in

Comment: Thank you very much! The 2nd option is cool, I'll consider the implementation of `expand()`. Also I considered something very similar to the 1st option before to post this question, but my problem was (and actually *is*) that I couldn't call `pipe()` on `this.kubernetesObjectList$`, as it's a `Subscribable<KubernetesObjectModel[]>` and it doesn't have the `pipe()` method. Maybe it should be `Observable`, not just `Subscribable`...

Comment: Thank you, I modified my services, so they return instances of `Observable<T[]>` instead of `Subscribable<T[]>`, reimplemented my poller according to your 1st suggestion and now it works great! I just didn't think that I could make API-service returning an `Observable` (it's my very first project with Angular, RxJS and TypeScript, to be frank). Again, thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to poll on an interval consider the trying the following:

```js
const intervalDelays$ = new BehaviorSubject(10000);

intervalDelays.pipe(
  switchMap(ms => ms === 0 ? EMPTY : interval(ms).pipe(
    concatMap(() => fetchDataObservableHere$)
  ))
);
```

`interval` uses a `setInterval` under the hood. Just be sure that `ms` is longer than `fetchDataObservableHere$` takes to *complete*. Otherwise you'll end up with backpressure issues.

If backpressure is a concern, you can do this:

```
const intervalDelays$ = new BehaviorSubject(10000);

intervalDelays.pipe(
  switchMap(ms => ms < 0
    // No wait? We'll assume it's "off"
    ? EMPTY
    // just an observable to start the recursive expand call.
    // 'start' doesn't matter. Could be `true` or anything, really.
    : of('start').pipe(
      expand(() => timer(ms).pipe(
        switchMap(() => fetchDataObservableHere$),
        tap(data => {
          // PROCESS DATA HERE
          // this ensures that it's done processing before you move on.
        }),
      )),
  ))
);
```

The above code will see incoming changes to the delay of the interval, and start a new inner observable that will recursively execute in such a way that it will wait for each value to come back and be processed before making another request.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben! That's so cool to receive an answer about RxJS from you personally. :-)